# The instance member 'key' can't be accessed

Tags: flutter

> The key inside AES() does not accept because  The instance member 'key' can't be accessed in an initializer.Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

```
 import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' ;
      class className extends StatefulWidget {
      className({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _className createState() => _classNameState();
}

class _classNameState extends State<className> {
  
  final iv =IV.fromLength(16);
  var key = Key.fromUtf8('b75524255a7f54d2726a951bb39204df');
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
```

Comment: Can you provide more code and the context of this error?

Comment: this all the code I put it inside stateFulwidget just that @quoci

Comment: Your problem is you are defining a Final value to a non constant value (`Key.fromUtf8('b75524255a7f54d2726a951bb39204df');`), so you either set final key as a null value `final key?` or remove Final keyword.

Comment: I edit my code you can see it @quim

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate `key` during the declaration.
Just declare `key` and instantiate it in a second moment (for example in the `initState()`).

Comment: can you see my code I edit it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a member variable (`key`) and then proceed to use it in the initialization of another member variable (`encrypter`). The simplest fix is to add the `late` keyword before the `encrypted` initialization.

```
late final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
```

Comment: I put late before final the error is in side (Super(Key:key))